# How do I manipulate (dump and load) Git index as text?

Tags: git

I've found myself in a need to perform a complex git history rewrite. Specifically, I need to remove most of the files and toss around a few remaining ones. E. g.:

```
$ pr -m -t <(/bin/tree a) <(/bin/tree b)
a                                   b
├── 5                               ├── renamed-3
├── 6                               └── renamed-4
└── foo                             
    └── bar                         0 directories, 2 files
        ├── 3                       
        ├── 4                       
        └── baz                     
            ├── 1                           
            └── 2                           

3 directories, 6 files
```

This can be easily done with `git filter-branch --tree-filter`. However, `--tree-filter` is slow, with a much faster alternative in form of `--index-filter`.

I tried to express my desired operations in terms of `git rm --cached` and `git mv --cached`, but it turned out to be quite ugly. It would be a lot easier if I could manipulate the contents of the index as text, using standard Unix tools (sed/grep/awk).

Is there a pair of Git commands that would allow to

- dump current contents of Git index to stdout as text in *some* format (one entry per line, including full path to the file);
- read text in the above format from stdin into Git index, fully replacing its current contents?

---

Desired usage example:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git magic-index-dump | awk "..." | git magic-index-replace'
```

Comment: `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index --index-info`. You'll need some massaging of the text in between, with awk or whatever.

Comment: @torek `git update-index --stdin` takes a different format than `git ls-index --stage` and does *not* work without a worktree (i. e. it adds _named_ files, not _specified_ files).

Comment: Right, I typed `stdin` but meant `index-info`, and likewise I typed `ls-index` instead of `ls-files`...

Comment: @torek Oh, `--index-info`? Do you know how does the "stage" field work? Also, I want to replace index, not append to index.

Comment: The stage number will be zero since you don't want to set up a conflicted merge. To remove a file, set its mode to `0`.

Comment: @torek So that's it. Removing files as you suggested seems overly complex, but I think I know how to invoke the desired behavior. Can you post your suggestion as an answer so I can edit it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185062/discussion-between-intelfx-and-torek).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index --index-info` can get you all the way there, though it's a bit clumsy in spots: removing a file means setting its mode to zero, and renaming a file amounts to *duplicate the line (to the end of the instructions) while changing the name; then set the mode to zero in the original line*.  The point of putting the new entry at the *end* is that it's possible that your desired new name matches the name of some existing file you plan to delete—if that can't happen, you don't need to be quite this tricky.

Inside a filter-branch operation there should never be any ongoing merge, so all stage numbers should be (and remain) zero all the way through the operation.

Answer (score 3):

*[This is an improvement on [torek's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53722759/857932), which was rejected as an edit.]*

It is possible to use `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index --index-info` to dump and append to index, respectively, using the same text format.

The format is described in [`git-update-index`(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_index_info):

> mode SP sha1 SP stage TAB path
>
> This format <...> matches git ls-files --stage output.

The "stage" field is used to represent a conflicting merge in the index. When there is no merge in progress, it will be always equal to `0`.

Note that `git update-index` only appends to index. To replace the index contents, it is possible to clear it before updating, or rather write to a different index file to avoid any kinds of data races caused by reading and updating/deleting the same file in the same pipeline.

Putting this into a one-liner would look rather messy, so we'll write a custom Git command `git-replace-index`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

: ${GIT_DIR:="$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"}
: ${GIT_INDEX_FILE:="$GIT_DIR/index"}
GIT_INDEX_NEW="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new"

GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_NEW" git update-index "$@"
rm -f "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
if [ -e "$GIT_INDEX_NEW" ]; then
    mv "$GIT_INDEX_NEW" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"   
fi
```

With this helper in place, the resulting pipeline would be:

```
git ls-files --stage | ... | git replace-index --index-info
```

Comment: There's a danger to doing this all in one pipeline as shown: `git rm -rq --cached .` and `git ls-files --stage` are running in (nominal) parallel, and it's possible for `git rm -r` to destroy the index before or during the `git ls-files` processing. Meanwhile, watch out for Git changing `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` to name some temporary rather than `.git/index`! You *can* remove the index file or use `git rm`, just be sure to invoke it *after* `git ls-files --stage` has completed.

Comment: @torek Valid point. I can simply delete the index file instead, utilizing POSIX unlink semantics.

Comment: You'll still have a race, though here you should almost always "win" in that `git ls-files --stage` is likely to get the file open in time. See comment-edit.

Comment: @torek Right. Then I'll write to a different (empty) index file and rename afterwards.

Comment: OK. Be aware as well that `git filter-branch` `eval`s some of these filters in a temporary directory that's not where the `.git` directory is, so be sure to respect `$GIT_DIR` as well. (Filter-branch is a giant shell script, and is actually pretty readable!)